# How do you include an optional input for an executable python script?

Tags: python

I'm a pretty novice programmer.

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that a python script takes an input when it's called in command prompt and has a default when no input is present.

Basically it's a program that would run one way by default `C:Program Files\Sample\Sample.exe` and a different way if you do something like `C:Program Files\Sample\Sample.exe "option 2"`. Is this possible?

Is there something in python that I have to do or in the conversion from .py to .exe? I'm using pyinstaller to convert the script.

Thank you in advance and sorry if this isn't very professionally asked.

Comment: You should look into the `sys` module for the fundamentals of how to obtain the arguments of your script. However, the `argparse` module offers a higher-level (and typically simpler to work with) framework for argument parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)? It contains the command line arguments, and the first value is the program itself.

```
import sys

thing = "default"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    thing = sys.argv[1]

print("Thing is: ", thing)
```

Run like this:

```
$ python3.7 ex.py
Thing is:  default
$ python3.7 ex.py a
Thing is:  a
```

You could also use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module, which offers more flexibility:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example.')
parser.add_argument('thing', type=str, nargs="?", default="default")

args = parser.parse_args()
print("Thing is", args.thing)
```

Which produces the same result:

```
$ python3.7 ex.py
Thing is default
$ python3.7 ex.py a
Thing is a
```

You could also use the [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) library, which provides even *more* flexibility:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('thing', default="default")
def program(thing):
    print("Thing is", thing)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    program()
```

Same thing:

```
$ python3.7 ex.py
Thing is default
$ python3.7 ex.py a
Thing is a
```

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Example

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def program(arguments):
    if arguments:
        for arg in arguments:
            print(arg + '\n')
    else:
        print('no arguments')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    program(sys.argv[1:])
```